# Marking Seams with Mirror Modifier?

Tags: modeling, uv

[image]

As you can see the mirrored part has solidified, and when I press z the geometry is lighter and not selectable. Is it possible to mark seams? :/

Comment: unclear...what you mean by "solified"? you can't select a mesh part created my the mirror, you can only select the original part which has modifier applied. Unless you apply the modifier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **modifiers tab**, any modifier that's in use has 4 buttons: Visible in Render, Visible in Object, Visible in Edit, and **Vertex selectable in Edit mode. Press the last one, the one with the form of an inverted triangle**. That should make the mirrored part be selectable in edit mode. Anyways, whatever you select there will also automatically be selected on the other part of the mesh that's the original mirrored and vice versa, because they are mirrored. **Making seams on whichever of them will make the seam on the other**, even if you did not select the mirrored vertex to be visible in edit mode.